# Blackberry Push Notifications

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I have a URL to which I give current date, given date, token_signature these all are to be send dynamically from the client side (device).

I have searched the Blackberry Push Notification [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/platform_services/push_overview.html) but I think it only takes static url in its order form. But as I am suppose to give dynamic values at run time how am I suppose to integrate push notification in my app that when on clicking it, it opens the app.
Blackberry OS 7.0.

Comment: http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Push%20Notification

Comment: I'm integrating, it doesn't recogines "PushMessageReader" this line:  PushMessageReader.process( pushInputStream, conn );

Comment: you dont have  PushMessageReader.java class ?

Comment: No, Do you have? And I'm also having Class Cast Exception.

Comment: Got the Class http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Applications_using_Push_Technology@tkb/22/3/PushMessageReader.java

Comment: there is a download demo app in my blog. just download and try it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30484/discussion-between-ahmad-shahwaiz-and-signare)